# How should I use the Set Bone Position node in UPBGE?

Tags: game-engine

In UPBGE, I have a rigged car, and I gave my rig a new logic node editor, and then I gave it a 4 key movement.

[image]

So in pose mode, when I, for example, move the root bone (whose customized shape is visible in the image above), the tires are rotating and the car is moving. But when I press "p" and run the game, the UPBGE just moves the whole car rather than acting like, for example, I'm in pose mode and I'm moving my desired bone.

How can I make that 4 Key Movement to effect only the bone and act as if the bone is in pose mode?

I want to do it in the `Logic Node Editor` .

I found a `Set Bone Position` node and gave my bone to it and replaced that node with a `Move Object` node but it is not moving the bone. I think I'm using the node incorrectly. How should I use that node?

[image]